# I need my Minecraft session ID!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need my session ID for a secret server plugin I'm making. I need my session ID to test it. How can I manually get a session ID? Can I do it in-game? Do I have to crash it to find my session ID? If I crash it does my session ID change? Just for those of you who would like to know, if I have to crash it I can't get F3 + c to crash my game. I'm on a Mac, is the crash command different? If someone could answer all these questions I will be amazed.

Comment: F3+C must be held down for 10 seconds.

Comment: And what version are you using?

Comment: May I know what version are you using? Because 1.9 is kinda different

Comment: why should you need it for a plugin, are you meaning the uuid of the player, wich never changes, even after renaiming?

Comment: Yes, I am using 1.9. No I do not mean the UUID of the player.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Session ID**

The Session ID can be found in your game log/crash report before the 1.9.1.

**Version**

In/After 1.9.1-pre3, the session ID has been removed from the game log/crash report.
[image]

Here is how the crash report looks like before 1.9.1 and after 1.9.1:
[image: Before 1.9.1]
This is 1.9 crash report
[image: After 1.9.1]
This is 1.9.2 crash report.

As a result, you can only view your session ID before 1.9.1.

**Game Log**

The Session ID can not only be found on crash report, it can also be found on the game log. (Before 1.9.1)
[image]

**Does my session ID changes if I logout?**

Yes

1st game log
[image]
After reopen Minecraft
[image]
**How to check session id without crashing the game?**

Just go to your .minecraft folder and you will see a folder called logs
[image]
Make sure Minecraft is launched. If it isn't, you will see the old session ID.
Inside the logs folder, you will see a text document called latest, open up latest and you should see your session ID.
[image]
**Extra**

Currently, there is no way to view your session ID in-game

Hold <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for 10 seconds to crash the game.

*Thats' it, I hope it helped :)*

Comment: if you only want to show a part of the screen, use snipping tool, wich is installed on every windows :)

Comment: Np, I am glad that I've helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for 10 seconds crash the game and get your session ID.

Comment: "if I have to crash it I can't get F3 + c to crash my game. I'm on a Mac, is the crash command different?". Not to mention the question was already answered quite extensively.